# Why does keras neural network predicts the same number for all different images?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, handwriting-recognition

I'm trying to use keras neural network of tensorflow to recognize the handwriting digit number. But idk why when i call `predict()`, it returns same results for all of input images.

Here is code:

```
  ### Train dataset ###
  mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
  (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
  x_train = x_train/255
  x_test = x_test/255

  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128,activation=tf.nn.relu))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10,activation=tf.nn.softmax))

  model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

  model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

The result looks like this:

```
Epoch 1/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 672us/step - loss: 0.2620 - accuracy: 0.9248
Epoch 2/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 1s 567us/step - loss: 0.1148 - accuracy: 0.9658
Epoch 3/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 1s 559us/step - loss: 0.0784 - accuracy: 0.9764
Epoch 4/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 1s 564us/step - loss: 0.0596 - accuracy: 0.9817
Epoch 5/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 1s 567us/step - loss: 0.0462 - accuracy: 0.9859
```

Then the code to use image to test is below:

```
  img = cv.imread('path/to/1.png')
  img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  img = cv.resize(img,(28,28))
  img = np.array([img])
    
  if cv.countNonZero((255-image)) == 0:
     print('')
  img = np.invert(img)
    
  plt.imshow(img[0])
  plt.show()
    
  prediction = model.predict(img)
  result = np.argmax(prediction)
  print(prediction)
  print(f'Result: {result}')
```

The result is:

[image: Input with number 1]

plt show:
[image: PlT show 1]

```
[[0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
Result: 3
```

[image: Input with number 2]

plt show
[image: PlT show 2]

```
[[0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
Result: 3
```

Comment: You are inverting your image when predicting `img = np.invert(img)` whereas the original dataset have number as higher value (so white digit (1) on black background(0)). Similarly the `img/255`. Do the same processing you do for training images on your test images/while predicting.

Comment: I see that if i remove the second ````img = np.invert(img)````, it return predictions with hight percent exactly, but if remove all of the ````img = np.invert(img)````, it give all wrong

Comment: what second `np.invert(img)` are you talking about? there is only one. `cv.countNonZero((255-image))` doesn't invert the actual image if that's what you are talking about

Comment: i checked my code again and see the second ````np.invert(img)````, but the ````cv.countNonZero((255-image))```` just use to check if image is a blank white background. :D

Comment: @HungDang can you give some feedback on the given answer (updated part)?

Comment: As i say, i just have to remove the second ````np.invert(img)````, and it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalize your data in inference time same what you did on the training set

```
img = np.array([img]) / 255
```

Check [this answer (Inference)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66191381/9215780) for more details.

---

Based on your 3rd comment, here are some details.

```
def input_prepare(img):            
    img = cv2.resize(img, (28, 28))   
    img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)   

    img = tf.cast(tf.divide(img, 255) , tf.float64)              
    img = tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0)   
    return img 

img = cv2.imread('/content/1.png')
orig = img.copy() # save for plotting later on 

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # gray scaling 
img = input_prepare(img)

plt.imshow(tf.reshape(img, shape=[28, 28]))
```

[image]

```
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(orig, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.title(np.argmax(model.predict(img)))
plt.show()
```

[image]

It works as expected. But because of resizing the image, the digits get broken and lose their spatial information. That seems ok for the model but if it gets much worse, then the model will predict wrong. A case examples

[image]

and the model predicts wrong for this.

```
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(orig, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.title(np.argmax(model.predict(img)))
plt.show()
```

[image]

To fix this we can apply `cv2.erode` to add some pixel after resizing, for example

```
def input_prepare(img):            
    img = cv2.resize(img, (28, 28))   
    img = cv2.erode(img, np.ones((2, 2)))
    img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)   

    img = tf.cast(tf.divide(img, 255) , tf.float64)              
    img = tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0)   
    return img
```

[image]

Not the best approach perhaps but now the model will understand better.

```
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(orig, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.title(np.argmax(model.predict(img)))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: so the ````img = np.invert(img)```` not helpful, right?

Comment: normally in  `mnist`, the background is black, and the foreground (or digit itself) is white. You just need to ensure the same view in the test (inference set) time.

Comment: The image cotains digits has white backgound and black foreground, so i use ````np.invert(img)```` to invert the background and foreground. I also check my code and i accidenttaly call ````np.invert(img)```` twice so the final image to predict has white background, the i clear the second, it work fine, but number 1 still not correct...:(

Comment: Have you normalized data in inference time as I mentioned above? Also, can you post your original image too?

Comment: Follow that answer link that I mentioned in this answer, it will surely solve the problem.

Comment: I tried, but nothing change, i've already post orginal image in topic

Comment: It works fine, now i trying to train it with digits greater than 9, like 10 to 17, but look like the predict not return true value

Comment: do you have a dummy dataset regarding digits above 10?