# MSINT - Image classification - value error incompatible shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-classification

I am beginning with image classification using keras. Tried a simple minst dataset for detecting numbers in images. Ran the model. However I wanted to test the model on my own dataset and facing some problem.

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    msint = tf.keras.datasets.mnist #28x28 images of hand written digits 0-9
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test,y_test) = msint.load_data()
    
    
    x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train,axis=1)
    x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test,axis=1)
    
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=3)

#Testing on my own image data
img2 = cv2.imread("981_cropped.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
(thresh, blackAndWhiteImage) = cv2.threshold(img2, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

z_predict = tf.keras.utils.normalize(blackAndWhiteImage,axis=1)
predictions = new_model.predict([z_predict])
```

Error:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 28, 28) for
> input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 28, 28),
> dtype=tf.float32, name='flatten_input'), name='flatten_input',
> description="created by layer 'flatten_input'"), but it was called on
> an input with incompatible shape (None, 28).
>
> ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer:
> expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784 but received input
> with shape (None, 28)

Comment: Your image only has a single axis with a value of 28 whereas the model expects an image of size (None, 28,28).

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66191381/9977321

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should resize the image before feeding it to your network. The model expects an image with shape `(28,28)`.

- Resize the image like this: `img2 = cv2.resize(img2, (28, 28 ))`
- As the model expects a batch dimension, you should add another dimension to your image like this: `z_predict = tf.expand_dims(z_predict,axis=0)`
- Notice that predictions will be probabilities of each class. If you want to get the class number of prediction, you can use of `np.argmax(prediction)`.

The modified code should be like this:

```
import cv2
img2 = cv2.imread("981_cropped.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img2 = cv2.resize(img2, (28, 28 ))      #resize image
(thresh, blackAndWhiteImage) = cv2.threshold(img2, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

z_predict = tf.keras.utils.normalize(blackAndWhiteImage,axis=1)

z_predict = tf.expand_dims(z_predict,axis=0)  # add batch dimension
predictions = model.predict(z_predict)
np.argmax(predictions)  # get predicted class
```