# How to predict MNIST data with trained model (expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784, but received input with shape (784, 1))

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have followed the tensorflow2 tutorial but now want to use the model to predict an image.

My code:

```
import tensorflow
import tensorflow_datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import numpy

def normalize_img(img, label):
  return tensorflow.cast(img, tensorflow.float32) / 255., label

(mnist_train, mnist_raw), mnist_info = tensorflow_datasets.load(
    'mnist',
    split=['train', 'test'],
    shuffle_files=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    with_info=True,
)

mnist_train = mnist_train.map(normalize_img, num_parallel_calls=tensorflow.data.AUTOTUNE)
mnist_train = mnist_train.cache()
mnist_train = mnist_train.shuffle(mnist_info.splits['train'].num_examples)
mnist_train = mnist_train.batch(128)
mnist_train = mnist_train.prefetch(tensorflow.data.AUTOTUNE)

mnist_test = mnist_raw.map(normalize_img, num_parallel_calls=tensorflow.data.AUTOTUNE)
mnist_test = mnist_test.batch(128)
mnist_test = mnist_test.cache()
mnist_test = mnist_test.prefetch(tensorflow.data.AUTOTUNE)

model = tensorflow.keras.models.Sequential([
  tensorflow.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tensorflow.keras.layers.Dropout(0.16),
  tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
])



model.compile(
    optimizer=tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001), 
    loss=tensorflow.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), 
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)

result = model.fit(mnist_train, epochs=6, validation_data=mnist_test)

it = mnist_test.as_numpy_iterator()
first = it.next()
images, labels = first[0], first[1]

plot.imshow(images[0].squeeze())
model(images[0].squeeze().flatten())
```

The last line gives the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
ipython-input-87-57d521ba8778> in <module>()
----> 1 model(images[0].squeeze().flatten())
1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    247         if value is not None and shape_as_list[int(axis)] not in {value, None}:
    248           raise ValueError(
--> 249               f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" is '
    250               f'incompatible with the layer: expected axis {axis} '
    251               f'of input shape to have value {value}, '
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_1" (type Sequential).
Input 0 of layer "dense_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784, but received input with shape (784, 1)
Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(784,), dtype=float32)
  • training=False
  • mask=None
```

As far as I can understand, the model operator() expects a 1 dimensional array, but I supply it with a 2 dimensional array, where the second dimension is 1 (which is essentially a 1 dim. array).

I have found this question: [Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66190989/input-0-of-layer-sequential-is-incompatible-with-the-layer-expected-axis-1-of)

But if I do reshape(1, 784) the error message switches to expecting dimension (28,28). If I do not flatten the array, I get the error that (28, 28) was supplied, but it wants (784).

Comment: Squeeze the unwanted dimension. For example, `data = np.squeeze(data, axis=-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the shape of `images[0].squeeze().flatten()`:

```
import numpy as np

print(np.shape(images[0].squeeze().flatten()))
```

```
(784,)
```

Your input is however `(None, 28, 28)`. So, you don't need the flatten (that is taken care of by the `Flatten` at the input). Also, you need the batch dimension. So you can do:

```
model(np.expand_dims(images[0, :], axis=0))
```

Note that if you want to input more images at once, it works fine:

```
model(images[0:10, :])
```

Because the batch dimension is there.